How to Handle Garbage Data from Scales After USB Reconnection in a .NET Application?
I am developing a .NET application using C#. In my app, I connect to a scale via USB and retrieve weight data. Normally, I can successfully get the correct weight data. However, when I disconnect the USB connection and reconnect it, the scale starts sending garbage data, like this:
00-F8-00-F8-00-F8-F8-86-06-F8-18-F8-66-F8-E6-80-98-80-00-F8-00-F8-00-F8-F8-86-06-F8-18-F8-66-F8-E6-80-98-80

When I test the same scenario using Hercules SETUP (a serial communication tool), it initially receives similar incorrect data. However, after a short period, the garbage data is corrected, and the correct weight data starts coming in. After this correction happens in Hercules, the correct data also starts being sent to my .NET application when I reconnect.
My Question:
How does Hercules handle and correct the corrupt or garbage data coming from the scales?
What should I do in my application to achieve the same behavior, so that I can handle this scenario and receive the correct data consistently after USB reconnection?
Additional Details:
The scales are connected via USB.
I am using a serial port in my application to read data from the scales.
This problem only occurs after disconnecting and reconnecting the USB cable.
I have researched extensively but haven't found a solution yet.

It will be nearly impossible to answer this without knowing what good data looks like, and how to interpret it.  Also, you are presenting the data here as a series of bytes, which means you are possibly losing information because the data actually comes in packets over the USB wire, where each packet can have multiple bytes in it.  Seeing the descriptors of the USB device would also help, so we can know if it's using any standard device classes and understand what drivers it would be using on the P.C. side.

@DavidGrayson Normally, when sending a value such as "20-20-30-2E-31-32-35-0D-0A" (it is 0.125), the values ​​received after unplugging and plugging into the USB are not numerical values.

Oh.  That's just an ASCII string so it's more illuminating to just write it as "  0.125\r\n".

Besides telling a scale to "SendWeight", there are usually other commands like: "ZeroScale". Or, "InitiateConfidenceTest".  And "SendResults".

@GerrySchmitz  I tried this but it didn't work

Maybe try "closing the port" before "unplugging". "Graceful degradation".

I recommend that you read all of the documentation for SerialPort, and ensure that you have set all the properties appropriately. You'll most likely need to set DtrEnable to true and RtsEnable to true.   Subscribe to all of the events: DataReceived, ErrorReceived, and PinChanged.

In the DataReceived event handler add the following code: if (e.EventType != SerialData.Chars) return;

Then in the PinChanged event handler add the following code: Debug.WriteLine($"SerialPort1_PinChanged - {e.EventType.ToString()}"); which should provide helpful information. Debug your code. Take some readings and then unplug the USB cable and see the message that's generated.

I solve this problem with installing CH340 driver.

The junk data you are getting looks like it could be caused by a baud rate mismatch.  I suggest that you connect to the serial port, set the correct baud rate, then  flush all previously received data using SerialPort.DiscardInBuffer, since it might have been received incorrectly using the wrong baud rate.  You might also need to call Read or ReadExisting to really get all the data.

I tried this but there is no change. i still get some problem

What happens if you comnect to the serial port, set the correct baud rate, and read as much data as you can for many seconds.  The data never goes back to normal?  It might be time to show us an [mcve].

One can detect when a USB device is added (plugged in) or removed (unplugged). If the USB cable is disconnected, you may consider disposing the instance of SerialPort which should avoid this issue. Prior to continuing, refer to the documentation for your serial port device on how to find the settings/property values needed for the instance of SerialPort used in the code below.
Try the following (for additional information see the comments throughout the code):
Create a new Windows Forms App (name: SerialPortDemo; .NET 8)
Pre-requisites

Download/install NuGet package: System.IO.Ports (v8.0.0)
Download/install NuGet package: System.Management (v8.0.0)

Create a class (name: SerialPortConnectionStatusUpdatedEventArgs.cs)
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SerialPortDemo
{
    public delegate void SerialPortConnectionStatusUpdatedEventHandler(object sender, SerialPortConnectionStatusUpdatedEventArgs e);

    public enum SerialPortConnectionStatusType
    {
        NotSet,
        Connected,
        Disconnected
    }

    public class SerialPortConnectionStatusUpdatedEventArgs : System.EventArgs
    {
        private SerialPortConnectionStatusType _connectionStatus;
        private string _message;

        public SerialPortConnectionStatusUpdatedEventArgs(SerialPortConnectionStatusType connectionStatus, string? message = null)
        {
            this._connectionStatus = connectionStatus;
            this._message = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(message) ? message : string.Empty;
        }

        public SerialPortConnectionStatusType ConnectionStatus
        {
            get
            {
                return this._connectionStatus;
            }
        }

        public string Message
        {
            get
            {
                return this._message;
            }
        }
    }
}

Create a class (name: UsbDeviceNotification.cs)
Note: This is used with an override to WndProc to detect USB device arrival and removal. The code was taken from here.
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SerialPortDemo
{
    public static class UsbDeviceNotification
    {
        public const int DbtDevicearrival = 0x8000; // system detected a new device        
        public const int DbtDeviceremovecomplete = 0x8004; // device is gone      
        public const int WmDevicechange = 0x0219; // device change event      
        private const int DbtDevtypDeviceinterface = 5;
        private static readonly Guid GuidDevinterfaceUSBDevice = new Guid("A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED"); // USB devices
        private static IntPtr notificationHandle;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr RegisterDeviceNotification(IntPtr recipient, IntPtr notificationFilter, int flags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnregisterDeviceNotification(IntPtr handle);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct DevBroadcastDeviceinterface
        {
            internal int Size;
            internal int DeviceType;
            internal int Reserved;
            internal Guid ClassGuid;
            internal short Name;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers a window to receive notifications when USB devices are plugged or unplugged.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="windowHandle">Handle to the window receiving notifications.</param>
        public static void RegisterUsbDeviceNotification(IntPtr windowHandle)
        {
            DevBroadcastDeviceinterface dbi = new DevBroadcastDeviceinterface
            {
                DeviceType = DbtDevtypDeviceinterface,
                Reserved = 0,
                ClassGuid = GuidDevinterfaceUSBDevice,
                Name = 0
            };

            dbi.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(dbi);
            IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(dbi.Size);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(dbi, buffer, true);

            notificationHandle = RegisterDeviceNotification(windowHandle, buffer, 0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Unregisters the window for USB device notifications
        /// </summary>
        public static void UnregisterUsbDeviceNotification()
        {
            UnregisterDeviceNotification(notificationHandle);
        }
    }
}

Create a class (name: HelperSerialPort.cs)
Note: Update the SerialPort property values in the code below to match the settings of your serial port device.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Management;

namespace SerialPortDemo
{
    public enum SerialPortBaudRate : int
    {
        Baud1200 = 1200,
        Baud2400 = 2400,
        Baud4800 = 4800,
        Baud9600 = 9600,
        Baud14400 = 14400,
        Baud19200 = 19200,
        Baud28800 = 28800,
        Baud38400 = 38400,
        Baud56000 = 56000,
        Baud57600 = 57600,
        Baud76800 = 76800,
        Baud115200 = 115200,
        Baud128000 = 128000,
        Baud230400 = 230400,
        Baud250000 = 250000,
        Baud256000 = 256000
    };

    

    public class HelperSerialPort : IDisposable
    {
        public event SerialPortConnectionStatusUpdatedEventHandler? ConnectionStatusUpdated;

        private string _dataReceived = string.Empty;
        public SerialPort? Port { get; private set; } = null;
        private string _portName = string.Empty;

        public bool Connect(string? portName, SerialPortBaudRate baudRate = SerialPortBaudRate.Baud9600)
        {
            try
            {
                //re-initialize
                _portName = string.Empty;

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(portName))
                    throw new Exception("Error - COM port not specified.");

                //if not null, dispose
                if (Port != null)
                    Dispose();

                //create new instance and set properties
                //all properties need to match settings of serial port device
                Port = new SerialPort(portName)
                {
                    BaudRate = (int)baudRate,
                    DataBits = 8,
                    DiscardNull = false, //whether null bytes are ignored when transmitted between the port and the receive buffer; default false
                    DtrEnable = true, //Data Terminal Ready; default: false
                    Encoding = Encoding.ASCII, //default: ASCII
                    Handshake = Handshake.None, //default: None
                    NewLine = "\r\n", //used with ReadLine and WriteLine; default: "\n"; 
                    Parity = Parity.None, //default: None
                    ReadBufferSize = 4096, //size in bytes; default: 4096; max value is 2147483647
                    ReadTimeout = 200, //number of milliseconds before a time-out occurs when a read operation does not finish
                    ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1, // number of bytes in the internal input buffer before a DataReceived event is fired; default: 1
                    RtsEnable = false, //Request to Send (RTS)
                    StopBits = StopBits.One, //number of stopbits per byte; default StopBits.One
                    WriteBufferSize = 2048, //size of the serial port output buffer; default: 2048
                    WriteTimeout = 50 //number of milliseconds before a time-out occurs when a write operation does not finish; default: -1 (InifiniteTimeout)
                };

                //subscribe to events
                Port.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;
                Port.ErrorReceived += Port_ErrorReceived;
                Port.PinChanged += Port_PinChanged;

                //open
                 Port.Open();

                //set value
                _portName = portName;

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code

                LogMsg($"Error (Connect) - {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (Port != null)
            {
                //unsubscribe from events
                Port.DataReceived -= Port_DataReceived;
                Port.ErrorReceived -= Port_ErrorReceived;
                Port.PinChanged -= Port_PinChanged;

                try
                {
                    if (Port.IsOpen)
                        Port.Close();

                    Port.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //do nothing
                    LogMsg($"Info (Dispose): {ex.Message}. This may occur when a serial port device cable is unplugged. It's recommended to close the application prior to unplugging the device cable. No action required.");
                }
            }
        }

        public static async Task<List<ComPortInfo>?> GetComPorts()
        {
            List<ComPortInfo>? comPortInfos = null;

            //queue to run on ThreadPool
            Task t = Task.Run(() => { comPortInfos = GetComPortsViaWmi(); });
            await Task.Yield();
            await t;

            return comPortInfos;
        }

        private static List<ComPortInfo> GetComPortsViaWmi()
        {
            List<ComPortInfo> portInfos = new List<ComPortInfo>();
            SortedDictionary<string, ComPortInfo> portDict = new SortedDictionary<string, ComPortInfo>();
            
            //get port names
            //don't use 'SerialPort.GetPortNames()' because it doesn't seem to update 
            //if USB device cable is unplugged

            //get serial port devices that may not be USB
            //if a driver is installed for a serial port device,
            //then the device may not be found by this query, but
            //will be found by querying 'Win32_PnPEntity'.
            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcherPnPEntity = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Caption, DeviceID, Name, PNPDeviceID, ProviderType FROM Win32_SerialPort"))
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject objPnPEntity in searcherPnPEntity.Get())
                {
                    if (objPnPEntity == null)
                        continue;

                    //get properties
                    string? caption = objPnPEntity["Caption"]?.ToString();
                    string? name = objPnPEntity["Name"]?.ToString();
                    string? deviceId = objPnPEntity["DeviceID"]?.ToString();
                    string? pnpDeviceId = objPnPEntity["PNPDeviceID"]?.ToString();
                    string? providerType = objPnPEntity["ProviderType"]?.ToString();

                    string connectionType = string.Empty;
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(providerType) && providerType.StartsWith("RS232"))
                        connectionType = "RS232";
                    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(caption) && caption.StartsWith("USB"))
                        connectionType = "USB";

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(deviceId) && !portDict.ContainsKey(deviceId))
                        portDict.Add(deviceId, new ComPortInfo() {Caption = caption, ConnectionType = connectionType, PnPDeviceId = pnpDeviceId, PortName = deviceId}); //add to Dictionary
                }
            }

            //get USB COM ports from 'Win32_PnPEntity'
            //if a driver is installed for a serial port device
            //this may result in a more descriptive name than 'COM1'.
            //this adds serial port devices that weren't found by querying 
            //'Win32_SerialPort'. For any serial port devices found in this query
            //and also found by the previous query, the information will be updated
            //Also "Select * From CIM_LogicalDevice where Caption like '%(COM%)%'"
            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcherPnPEntity = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Caption, Name, PNPDeviceID FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE PNPClass = 'Ports' and Caption like '%(COM%)%'"))
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject objPnPEntity in searcherPnPEntity.Get())
                {
                    if (objPnPEntity == null)
                        continue;

                    //get properties
                    string? caption = objPnPEntity["Caption"]?.ToString();
                    string? name = objPnPEntity["Name"]?.ToString();
                    string? pnpDeviceId = objPnPEntity["PNPDeviceID"]?.ToString();

                    string portName = string.Empty;
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && name.ToUpper().Contains("COM"))
                    {
                        //Option 1 (substring):
                        portName = name.Substring(name.IndexOf("(") + 1, name.IndexOf(")") - name.IndexOf("(") - 1);

                        /*
                        //Option 2 (regex):
                        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(name, @"(?<portName>COM\d{1,3})");
                        if (matches != null && matches.Count > 0)
                        {
                            portName = matches[0].Groups["portName"].Value;
                        }
                        */

                        if (!portDict.ContainsKey(portName))
                        {
                            string? connectionType = string.Empty;

                            //ToDo: verify this works with your serial port device
                            //PowerShell:  Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\Cimv2 -Query "Select * From Win32_PnPEntity where PNPClass = 'Ports'" 
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pnpDeviceId) && pnpDeviceId.StartsWith("USB"))
                                connectionType = "USB";

                            //add to dictionary
                            portDict.Add(portName, new ComPortInfo() { Caption = caption, ConnectionType = connectionType, PnPDeviceId = pnpDeviceId, PortName = portName}); //add to Dictionary
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //update dictionary
                            if (!name.StartsWith("Communications Port ("))
                            {
                                //update caption - if a driver is installed,
                                //this may contain a more descriptive name
                                portDict[portName].Caption = caption;

                                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(portDict[portName].ConnectionType))
                                    portDict[portName].ConnectionType = "USB";
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ComPortInfo> kvp in portDict)
            {
                //add to List
                portInfos.Add(kvp.Value);
            }

            return portInfos;
        }

        private static void LogMsg(string msg, bool includeTimestamp = true)
        {
            if (includeTimestamp)
                msg = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")} - {msg}";

            //ToDo: add desired code
            Debug.WriteLine(msg);
        }

        public void OnConnectionStatusUpdated(SerialPortConnectionStatusType connectionStatus, string message)
        {
            //if there are subscribers, raise event
            if (ConnectionStatusUpdated != null)
                ConnectionStatusUpdated(this, new SerialPortConnectionStatusUpdatedEventArgs(connectionStatus, message));
        }

        private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;

            //if (e.EventType != SerialData.Chars) 
            //    return;

            try
            {
                //Option 1:
                //if data sent from serial port device ends with a line feed and/or newline
                //use 'ReadLine' - ensure 'NewLine' property value is properly set
                //LogMsg($"Port_DataReceived: {sp.ReadLine()}");

                //Option 2:
                //if data sent from serial port device doesn't end with a line feed and/or newline
                //use 'ReadExisting'
                LogMsg($"Port_DataReceived: {sp.ReadExisting()}");
                
                //Option 3:
                //if data sent from serial port device contains non-printable characters such as [ACK]: 0x06
                //then use the following to read the data
                /*
                byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];

                int bytesRead = 0;
                int offset = 0;
                int totalBytes = 0;
                do
                {
                    //read
                    bytesRead = sp.Read(buffer, offset, 1);

                    totalBytes += bytesRead;
                    offset = totalBytes;
                } while (sp.BytesToRead > 0);

                byte[] dataBytes = new byte[totalBytes];

                //copy data to appropriately sized array
                Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, dataBytes, 0, totalBytes);

                //----------------------------------------
                //for debugging, output the HEX values
                //----------------------------------------
                string dataReceivedBytesAsHex = string.Empty;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataBytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                        dataReceivedBytesAsHex += " ";

                    dataReceivedBytesAsHex += dataBytes[i].ToString("X2");
                }

                LogMsg($"dataBytes (HEX): { dataReceivedBytesAsHex }");

                //----------------------------------------
                
                //convert byte[] to string using the encoding specified
                //for the SerialPort instance
                _dataReceived = sp.Encoding.GetString(dataBytes);
                LogMsg($"Port_DataReceived: '{_dataReceived}'");

                */
            }
            catch(TimeoutException ex)
            {
                LogMsg($"{ex.Message}. Check that property value for 'NewLine' matches setting for serial port device.");
                throw;
            }
        }

        private void Port_ErrorReceived(object sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;

            LogMsg($"Port_ErrorReceived: {e?.ToString()}");
        }

        private void Port_PinChanged(object sender, SerialPinChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //this may be used if your device has a driver and the driver supports it
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;

            LogMsg($"PinChanged: EventType: '{e.EventType.ToString()}'");

            if (e.EventType.ToString() == "DsrChanged")
            {
                if (sp.DsrHolding)
                {
                    string msg = $"Port_PinChanged - Connected.";
                    LogMsg($"Port_PinChanged - {msg}");
                    OnConnectionStatusUpdated(SerialPortConnectionStatusType.Connected, msg);
                }  
                else
                {
                    //for a USB serial port device if using a driver
                    //and the driver supports it, this will occur
                    //when the USB cable is unplugged
                    string msg = "Disconnected. Ensure cable is plugged in.";
                    LogMsg($"Port_PinChanged - {msg}");
                    OnConnectionStatusUpdated(SerialPortConnectionStatusType.Disconnected, msg);

                    //ToDo: add code for what to do if USB cable is unplugged
                    //Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        public void SendData(string data, byte[] dataBytes, bool sendOneByteAtATime = true)
        {
            if (Port != null)
            {
                if (sendOneByteAtATime)
                {
                    foreach (byte val in dataBytes)
                    {
                        //convert byte to byte[]
                        byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[] { val };
                        Port.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1); //sleep
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Port.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1); //sleep
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Rename Form1.cs to FrmMain.cs. In the Properties Window (View => Properties Window) set text property to "SerialPort Demo".
In the Designer, double-click FrmMain to add the Load event handler.
In the Designer, add the following to the form:

Label (name: labelComPort)
ComboBox (name: comboBoxComPorts)
Button (name: buttonConnectDisconnect; Text: Disconnected)
Double-click the button to add the Click event handler

The form should look similar to the following:

Modify the code in FrmMain.cs with the following:
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SerialPortDemo
{
    public partial class FrmMain : Form
    {
        private BindingList<ComPortInfo> _comPorts = new BindingList<ComPortInfo>();
        private Color _colorConnected = Color.LawnGreen;
        private Color _colorDisconnected = Color.OrangeRed;
        private HelperSerialPort? _helper = null;
        private string? _portName = string.Empty;

        public FrmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonConnectDisconnect.BackColor = _colorDisconnected;
            buttonConnectDisconnect.Text = "Disconnected";
            buttonConnectDisconnect.Refresh();

            //set properties
            comboBoxComPorts.DataSource = _comPorts;
            comboBoxComPorts.DisplayMember = "Caption";
            comboBoxComPorts.ValueMember = "PortName";

            //create new instance
            _helper = new HelperSerialPort();

            //subscribe to event(s)
            _helper.ConnectionStatusUpdated += Helper_ConnectionStatusUpdated;

            UpdateComPortInfo();
        }

        private void Connect()
        {
            ComPortInfo? portInfo = (ComPortInfo?)comboBoxComPorts.SelectedItem;

            if (portInfo != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(portInfo.PortName))
            {
                LogMsg($"Connecting to '{portInfo.Caption}'...");
                
                if (_helper != null)
                {
                    if (_helper.Connect(comboBoxComPorts?.SelectedValue?.ToString(), SerialPortBaudRate.Baud9600))
                    {
                        buttonConnectDisconnect.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            buttonConnectDisconnect.BackColor = _colorConnected;
                            buttonConnectDisconnect.Text = "Connected";
                            buttonConnectDisconnect.Refresh();
                        });

                        //set value
                        _portName = comboBoxComPorts?.SelectedValue?.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void Disconnect()
        {
            LogMsg($"Disconnecting from '{_portName}'...");

            //dispose SerialPort instance
            _helper?.Disconnect();

            _portName = string.Empty;
            buttonConnectDisconnect.Invoke(() =>
            {
                buttonConnectDisconnect.BackColor = _colorDisconnected;
                buttonConnectDisconnect.Text = "Disconnected";
                buttonConnectDisconnect.Refresh();
            });
        }

        private void Helper_ConnectionStatusUpdated(object sender, SerialPortConnectionStatusUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            LogMsg($"Helper_ConnectionStatusUpdated - {e.ConnectionStatus}");
            if (e.ConnectionStatus == SerialPortConnectionStatusType.Disconnected)
                Disconnect();
        }

        private void LogMsg(string msg, bool includeTimestamp = true)
        {
            if (includeTimestamp)
                msg = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")} - {msg}";

            //ToDo: add desired code
            Debug.WriteLine(msg);
        }

        private async void UpdateComPortInfo()
        {
            //clear existing data
            _comPorts.Clear();

            //get port names
            List<ComPortInfo>? portInfos = await HelperSerialPort.GetComPorts();

            if (portInfos != null)
            {
                bool portNameExists = false;
                foreach (ComPortInfo pInfo in portInfos)
                {
                    if (pInfo.PortName == _portName)
                        portNameExists = true; //set value

                    //add to BindingList
                    _comPorts.Add(pInfo);
                }

                //if connected and USB serial port device cable is unplugged, then disconnect
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_portName) && !portNameExists)
                {
                    LogMsg($"'{_portName}' no longer exists. Check cable connection.");

                    //update button text and color and dispose of SerialPort instance
                    //if not already disposed.
                    Disconnect();
                }     
            }
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);

            if (m.Msg == UsbDeviceNotification.WmDevicechange)
            {
                switch ((int)m.WParam)
                {
                    case UsbDeviceNotification.DbtDeviceremovecomplete:
                        UpdateComPortInfo();
                        break;
                    case UsbDeviceNotification.DbtDevicearrival:
                        UpdateComPortInfo();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void buttonConnectDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //create reference
            System.Windows.Forms.Button btn = (System.Windows.Forms.Button)sender;

            if (btn.Text == "Connected")
            {
                Disconnect();
            }
            else if (btn.Text == "Disconnected")
            {
                Connect();
            }
        }

        private void FrmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_helper != null)
                _helper.Dispose();
        }
    }
}


Here's some additional info that may be useful:
Open PowerShell and run the following:

Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\Cimv2 -Query "Select * From Win32_SerialPort Where Name like '%COM%'"
Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\Cimv2 -Query "Select * From Win32_SerialPortConfiguration"
Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\Cimv2 -Query "Select * From Win32_PnPEntity where PnPClass = 'Ports' and Name like '%COM%'"
mode
 Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM' (or reg query HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM)
chgport

